# Custom font in WPF application only works in design mode but not in the build

Tags: wpf, fonts

Recently I have a problem when using custom font in my WPF application. I added a custom font in my project using methods described in [Packaging Fonts with Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx). It works fine in design mode but when I run the application, it doesn't work and seems to use default font instead. To find the reason:

- I downloaded a free font from internet, and used same way to refer it. It worked very well in both situations.
- I created a new WPF project, and added the custom font in this new project. It unexpectedly worked. I compared the new project and my problem project, the difference is that I use .Net 3.5 in my old project, and .Net 4.0 in the new project. After I changed the old project to use .Net 4.0, the problem is resolved.  However, .Net 4.0 is not allowed in my old project, so that I want to find a solution based on .Net 3.5.
- by the way. I tried to build the font file as both content and resource.  Also, I tried to use  absolute and relevant path. It didn't work.

Looking forward to your help. Thanks very much.

Regards,
Yupeng

Comment: You should at least share example lines where you are referencing the font, there's too many things here to guess what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the font family whose name includes Medium/Light or other font key words will have the problem described above. When I used code to load the font files, the loaded font family names were different from that shown in the font files. So I assuming that the key words in the font name will be removed automatically when loading.

To solve the problem, I recoded the names(loaded by code) and used them to refer to my custom font family. It works well in the build but does work in the design mode now. Comment/Uncomment will be helpful to switch.

I think the easiest way should be to change the font family name by removing the key words, but I don't have permission and I didn't try it.