# Sinhala font is not shown properly

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

In a wpf application I have entered some text in sinhala to few labels.
In the design time sinhala font is shown properly as in the below image.

[image]

but when I start debugging, arrangement of characters is changed. see below image.

[image]

Font of the labels is Segoe UI. I have checked changing it to the default Sinhala font in Windows 7 (Iskoola Pota) but the problem exists.

How can I fix this?
I'm using VS 2010 on Windows7, Target framework is .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745650(v=vs.110).aspx Sinhala script is not supported in WPF. Would WinForms be an option? Doesn't seem to be a problem there.

Comment: Also: seems to be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720446/custom-font-in-wpf-application-only-works-in-design-mode-but-not-in-the-build?rq=1

Comment: @LocEngineer In WinForms it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745650(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745650(v=vs.110).aspx) Sinhala script is not supported in WPF. No problem in WinForms, so better go with that.